# Google Oauth login window doesn't work properly

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-security

I have project Java Spring + React.js.

**My problem**

On my site there is a button by clicking on which the user should be authorized via Google.The problem is that Google OAuth Login UI simply does not appear.The following error appears on the Google console.[image]

But still, this Google Login UI can be obtained if i go to the "Application" section. And by clicking on this tab  Google, I can successfully log in.
[image]

This is my security config code for Google OAuth 
[image]

This is my application.properties file 
[image: ![enter image description here]

In React side I have a button to click on which this function will be fulfilled.

```
 onOAuth2LiginClick = () => {
  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize/google", {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  });
};
```

For several days I can not find any information about this.How can I make this login window appear on my site? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to direct the browser to Google's OAuth2 endpoint -- i.e., via a link or using `window.location=...` -- instead of making a "backend" axios / XMLHttpRequests call to the endpoint.

From what I can see, if you just link the user to your `localhost:3000/oauth2/authorize/google` endpoint, it should probably work.

The exact flow is a bit different depending if you're doing server-side or client-side OAuth, but in either case basically you need to send the user to Google's auth url, then after authentication Google will send (redirect) the user back to the url you specify.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I just write **window.location.href=localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize/google** in my function.But it works only on the localhost. If i write following **mysite.com/oauth2/authorize/google** it will just redirect me to this link and nothing will happen

Comment: Ok that seems to be a separate issue, that your service on "mysite.com" isn't working.  It should redirect you to Google just like your service on localhost.  The issue could be configuration, security settings, etc.  If you have access to the logs on the other site, maybe you can see what's going on there.  Feel free to reach out again if you need a follow-up.

Comment: Let me explain a little. My application is divided into 2 versions; one is located on a local host and another is on a cloud(Heroku). The code is absolutely the same for all versions. The only thing I am changing is the link to Google OAuth on the React side and the return link on the Spring side.  In the version that is on the cloud, I change these links to **https://herokuapp.com/oauth2/authorize/google** and **https://herokuapp.com/customer/oauth2/callback/google**. And in the Google console, there are no errors.And there is no other place where I can see the errors

Comment: @MaximSukhodolets Sorry I didn't see your reply until now.  Were you able to solve the heroku problem?  Curious to what it was.  Take care.

Comment: Oh, I did not manage to solve this problem, I continued to do other work. But, since you answered my original question, I marked this question as resolved. I will return to this problem after solving the current tasks.Thanks for the help @peekay